# woocommerce cart not working properly with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Its my first time that I'm using woocommerce and I'm having some issue on my cart page when I added more than 1 product and increase or decrease any product it will increase quantity of all products.

For example : I've added product a with quantity 2 and product b with quantity 7

if I increase product b to 8 then product a quantity will also increased to 8

Code :

```
<script>
jQuery('.plus').on('click',function(e){
var val = parseInt(jQuery('input[title="Qty"]').val());

jQuery('input[title="Qty"]').val( val+1 );
});

jQuery('.minus').on('click',function(e){
var val = parseInt(jQuery('input[title="Qty"]').val());
if(val !== 0){

jQuery('input[title="Qty"]').val( val-1 );
} });
</script>
```

And one more thing price is remains same even if I add increase product or decrease

HTML output : goo.gl/h3w4IQ

Actual cart page : goo.gl/9ynStK

Please let me know why this jQuery code not working and what to do to increase / decrease price also as per product quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery code, you have selected all of the DOMs `input` while doing plus or minus. You actually needed a specific selector to change only the value of adjacent input. Please replace your code with this one. I have tested it and it works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Attach event on plus
    // We delegate the event to document
    // So that even if there are 100 of plus buttons
    // It would not slow down the page
    $(document).on( 'click', '.plus', function(e) {
        // Get the right element
        var elem = $(this).prev('.qty'),
        // and its value
        val = parseInt( elem.val() );
        // Sanitize the value
        if ( isNaN( val ) ) {
            val = 0;
        }
        if ( val < 0 ) {
            val = 0;
        }
        // Now increase it
        elem.val( ++val ).trigger('change');
    } );

    // Similar appraoch for the minus button
    $(document).on( 'click', '.minus', function(e) {
        // Get the right element
        var elem = $(this).next('.qty'),
        val = parseInt( elem.val() );
        // Sanitize the value
        if ( isNaN( val ) ) {
            val = 0;
        }
        // decrease the value
        val = val - 1;
        // but not a negative
        if ( val < 0 ) {
            val = 0;
        }
        // Set it
        elem.val( val ).trigger('change');
    } );
});
```

Comment: cool it works but still price is not increasing / decreasing with this

Comment: Well that is beyond what I can offer, because I think it needs to go to the server to calculate all the pricing. Maybe someone else can help you with that. But in my experience, when you increase product quantity in cart, you ask the user to update it, or do an ajax call to update it from server too.

Comment: well its really great help for me thanks :) btw do you know how to call ajax to update cart when user increase quantity ?

Comment: You say you are using WooCommerce for managing the cart If I remember correctly, WooCommerce carts have update button which the user needs to click to update the quantity. However, I found a plugin which will update the cart through ajax https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-cart/ You might want to give it a try. Also I have changed the JS which might be required for this plugin to work with your plus and minus button.